# How to define heterogenous std::map using boost::variant in "two dimensional manner"

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-mpl, boost-variant

I would be happy to get and advice how to deal with boost::variant in "two dimensional manner". Sounds strange but let my code say more (hopefully):

I have coded a class called Parameter:

```
template<typename PARAM_TYPE, typename DATA_TYPE=double>
class Parameter : public quantity<PARAM_TYPE, DATA_TYPE>
{
...
}
```

Example usage of my Parameter as defined above:

```
Parameter<si::length, double> SampleParameter1;
Parameter<si::dimensionless, short> SampleParameter2;
```

As I tried to explain by example above, I can define several Parameter types using the `boost::units::si::???` and different data type like `double, short, int` etc.

My GOAL is to construct a `std::map` container which can store instances of any `Parameter` type (as sampled above).

Therefore I have declared:

```
typedef boost::variant<Parameter<si::dimensionless, short>, Parameter<si::length, double> > SupportedParameterTypes;
std::map<int, SupportedParameterTypes> myMapStorage;
```

This works pretty well but have one big disadvantage I would like to solve - I have to define every single combination of Parameter type I would like to support in `SupportedParameterTypes` type as defined above.

My idea was to define boost::mpl::vector constaining all the Parameter types I would like to support:

```
typedef boost::mpl::vector<si::dimensionless, si::length> ParameterTypes;
```

And all the possible Parameter data types being supported on the other hand:

```
typedef boost::mpl::vector<short, int, float, double> ParameterDataTypes;
```

There comes my troubles:

```
typedef typename boost::make_variant_over<ParameterTypes>::type ParameterTypeVariants;
typedef typename boost::make_variant_over<ParameterDataTypes>::type ParameterDataVariants;

typedef boost::variant<Parameter<ParameterTypeVariants, ParameterDataVariants> > SupportedParameterTypes;
```

But to define `boost::variant` of something (`Parameter`) which is defineed by some other `boost::variant` seems not to work :o(

**QUESTION**: How to define `std::map` container holding all my `Parameter` types defined in appropriate `boost::mpl::vector`s?

I would like to kindly ask you for help solving this issue. Maybe it is not good idea/principle at all to code it as I wrote, who knows. My goal is to have a flexible storage by std::map to be capable to hold all my Parameters without having my code ambiguous. Looking for smart solution of course :o)

Many thanks in advance for any reply to my question / request for help

Comment: why two `mpl` vectors that separate `si` types and `data` types (making relation between them not so obvious) are better than something simple like  `boost::variant<Parameter<si::dimensionless, short>, Parameter<si::length, double> >`?

Comment: The reason why I need the two types separated is that any parameter type can be mated with any data type. There are about 20 si:: types and about 4 data ones. That would produce huge amount of combinations I would like to avoid. Anyway, thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 3):

You may produce all your pairing with something like

```
template <typename Seq, typename T1, typename T2>
struct cartesian_parameters_helper;

template <std::size_t...Is, typename T1, typename T2>
struct cartesian_parameters_helper<std::index_sequence<Is...>, T1, T2>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t size1 = std::tuple_size<T1>::value;
    using type = boost::variant<
        Parameter<
            std::tuple_element_t<Is / size1, T1>,
            std::tuple_element_t<Is % size1, T2>
            >...>;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct cartesian_parameters
{
    using type = typename cartesian_parameters_helper<
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<T1>::value
                                 * std::tuple_size<T2>::value>,
        T1, T2>::type;
};
```

And then use it as

```
using SupportedParameterTypes =
    cartesian_parameters<std::tuple<si::dimensionless, si::length>,
                         std::tuple<short, int, float, double>>::type;
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/JxSB40)

Comment: I am trying to implement my stuff using this proposal but it seems to be C++14 specific - at least I cannot find std::index_sequence<> valid for C++11. Is there any analogy existing for C++11? For example in Boost library? Many thanks in advance...

Comment: There are several implementation of `index_sequence` and `make_index_sequence` on SO.